# Frage nach dem Kasus in der Nominalisierung

Tags: grammatical-case, nominalization

Der ursprüngliche Satz ist:

> (S) Ich erkenne dies als einen Hund

nach der Nominalisierung:

> (N1) die Erkennung dieses Gegenstands als **einen** Hund
>
> (N2) die Erkennung dieses Gegenstands als **eines** Hund
>
> (N3) die Erkennung dieses Gegenstands als **ein** Hund

Welches ist richtig? Wahrscheinlich ist (N1) richtig.

Aber laut Langenscheidet Dictionary:

> der Kasus des Substantivs nach "als" richtet sich nach dem Kasus des Substantivs od. Pronomens, auf das es sich bezieht: **Ihm** als erfahren**em** Autofahrer hätte das nicht passieren dürfen; Wir werden **ihn** als gut**en** Mensch**en** in Erinnerung behalten; Anstatt eines Genitivs steht aber meist der Nominativ: der Ruf meines Vaters als Arzt

Vielen Dank im Voraus für eure Hilfe!

Comment: Anmerkung: Die Nominalisierung von _erkennen_ ist nicht _die Erkennung_, sondern _das Erkennen_.

Answer (score 2):

Du hast die Antwort ja schon selbst geschrieben:

> Anstatt eines Genitivs steht aber meist der Nominativ: *der Ruf meines Vaters als Arzt*

Wie in diesem Beispiel bereits gezeigt, benutzt man in so einer Konsellation Fall aber anstelle eines unbestimmten Artikels den Nullartikel (d.h. man lässt den Artikel weg).

Also:

> die Erkennung dieses Gegenstands als Hund.

Answer (score 2):

Der ursprüngliche Satz (Ich erkenne dies als einen Hund.) klingt nicht besonders natürlich. Zur Erklärung verwende ich deshalb einen anderen Satz, der aber die gleiche Grammatik hat.

1: Lieschen Müller bezeichnet Herrn Schmidt in ihrem neuen Buch **als einen Verbrecher**.

Sowohl ‚Herrn Smidt‘ als auch ‚einen Verbrecher‘ sind Akkusativ und also kongruent. Wenn wir nun ‚bezeichnen‘ nominalisieren, erhalten wir:

2: Das Bezeichnen des Herrn Schmidts **als ein**(en/es) Verbrecher(s), wurde von vielen Kritikern beanstandet.

Nun ist ‚Herrn Schmidts‘ Genitiv und nicht mehr Akkusativ. Laut Langenscheidt haben wir eine Wahl: wir können ‚eines Verbrechers‘ verwenden, also Genitiv, oder den unbestimmten Artikel weglassen und nur ‚Verbrecher‘ sagen, im Nominativ. Jedenfalls wäre es falsch, den Akkusativ aus Satz (1) unverändert zu übernehmen.

Der Duden stimmt zu: „Steht das Bezugswort im Nominativ, Dativ oder Akkusativ, dann muss der Anschluss im gleichen Fall erfolgen […] Wenn jedoch das Bezugswort im Genitiv steht, dann gibt es zwei Möglichkeiten. Enthält die *als*-Gruppe ein Artikelwort, steht sie im Genitiv […] Enthält sie kein Artikelwort, wird sie in der Regel in den Nominativ gesetzt.“ (https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Funktionen-von-als)

**Fazit:** ‚als eines Hundes‘ ist ebenso richtig wie ‚als Hund‘. Dagegen ist ‚als einen Hund‘ leider falsch.

Answer (score 0):

Ganz klar die Akkusativ-Variante, denn "Hund" bezieht sich auf das Erkennen, auf die Erkennung, so wie der Originalsatz (S) es ja schon vorgibt, daher also die (N1) als einzig richtige Lösung.

Die vorgegebenen Antworten beinhalten *alle* den unbestimmten Artikel von "Hund", da ist mit dem Auslassen des Artikels nicht geholfen. Und das passt auch mit Langenscheidt zusammen.

Comment: "Die Erkennung" steht aber mit Genitiv, im Gegensatz zu "Ich erkenne", das mit Akkusativ steht. Da kann man in den Satz mit "die Erkennung" nicht einfach trotzdem den Akkusativ reinmogeln, das funktioniert nicht.

Comment: @HalvarF  Ja, das Nomen "Erkennung" zieht den Genitiv nach sich, der hier schon mit "dieses Gegenstands" besetzt wurde; jetzt auch noch den "Hund" dazu zu fügen, würde eigentlich einen weiteren Genitiv erzwingen, was stilistisch sehr unglücklich, leicht mißverständlich und ist zu vermeiden. Daher muss der Satz dann entweder ganz neu aufgestellt werden - oder man bleibt bei der ursprünglichen Struktur und formuliert den 2. Genitiv in zulässig anderer Art.- Der ganze Satz ist durch die Einführung "dieses Gegenstandes" schon absturzgefährdet.

Comment: In meinem Sprachgefühl müsste der Satz eher so lauten: "Das Erkennen dieses Gegenstandes als das eines Hundes" , was stilistisch auch nicht sehr glücklich klingt. Aber nur die zusätzliche Einführung der Konjunktion "als das" mit Akkusativ kann die bevorstehende Total-Konfusion verhindern. Wie gesagt, der ganze Satz ist sehr unglücklich aufgestellt; der von "erkennen" geborgte Akkusativ mit "als" ist zwar 2.Wahl, bringt aber mehr Klarheit mit sich.

Answer (score -2):

Laut meiner spontanten Sprachgefühl-Reaktion war nur "N0" richtig:

> die Erkennung dieses Gegenstands als Hund

Warum, konnte ich mir erst aus der Antwort von @MarkOxford erklären.

Mit

> (N2) die Erkennung dieses Gegenstands als **eines** Hundes

will sich mein Sprachgefühl dagegen ganz und gar nicht anfreunden.